# How thoroughly was "Look Who's Back" researched?

Tags: german-language, timur-vermes, look-whos-back

The novel *Look Who's Back*, about the experiences of Adolf Hitler reawaking in 2011 Germany, necessarily contains a certain amount of detail - even if only in Hitler's internal monologue - about the Third Reich, Nazi Germany, and Hitler's personal life.

**How much research did Timur Vermes do during the writing of this book?** I'm interested in both *how much* detail he included - is it mostly common knowledge to Germans, or did he dig up a lot of obscure historical facts as well? - and *how accurate* it all is.